# Correctly recognise an int[] passed as a varargs parameter

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions, autoboxing

There seems to be an edge case between the autoboxing and the varargs system for primitive arrays. Is there a clean (i.e. non-reflection) way around this?

**Example:**

```java
public class Test {
  class A<T> {
    public void a(T... ts) {
      System.out.println(ts.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " of " + ts[0].getClass().getCanonicalName() + " = " + Arrays.toString(ts));
    }

  }

  public void test() {
    // These all work fine - presumably all parameters are autoboxed.
    new A().a(1, 2, 3);
    new A().a(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    new A().a(1L, 2L, 3L);
    // You can even mix them up - which is unexpected.
    new A().a(1.0f, 2.0d, 3L);
    // Works fine - even though I get a "non-varargs call to varargs method with inexact argument type ..." hint.
    new A().a(new Integer[]{1, 1});
    // No hint - and doesn't do as intended.
    new A().a(new int[]{1, 1});
    // Works fine.
    new A<Integer>().a(new Integer[]{1, 1});
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      new Test().test();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }

}
```

Prints

```java
java.lang.Object[] of java.lang.Integer = [1, 2, 3]
java.lang.Object[] of java.lang.Double = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
java.lang.Object[] of java.lang.Long = [1, 2, 3]
java.lang.Object[] of java.lang.Float = [1.0, 2.0, 3]
java.lang.Integer[] of java.lang.Integer = [1, 1]
java.lang.Object[] of int[] = [[I@4d815146]
java.lang.Integer[] of java.lang.Integer = [1, 1]
```

Notice that the int[] does not print correctly - it seems to be being boxed into an `Object[]` whose first value is my `int[]`. Everything else seems to box nicely.

I want the `int[]` call to print correctly without breaking the others.

P.S. If you can do it by reflection, by all means post. I'd just prefer not to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to add

```
String text;
if (ts[0] instanceof int[])
    text = Arrays.toString((int[]) ts[0]);
else
    text = Arrays.toString(ts);
```

I suspect there is an Apache common library to do this for you, but I don't know which one.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas Peter. BTW - it should be `it[0] instanceof int[]`.

Comment: This post holds the correct answer - please see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16856344/823393) for my implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

It prints perfectly, and there is no boxing going on. The object you are passing in *is* an Array of `int`, which Java writes as default writes as `[I@...`. Java won't look inside the `Array` and try to autobox the `int`s for you.

To get prettier looking printouts, you can take a look at @PeterLawrey:s answer.

Comment: It looks like there is boxing going on. The `int[]` is being boxed into an `Object[1]` whose first item is my `int[]`. Although that isn't actually boxing in the strictest sense is it. Boxing wraps `int`s in `Integer`s etc.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: NO, that is *varargs*, has nothing to do with boxing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hack around with Peter's idea and this now seems to work fine. It looks rather horrid but I think if I hide it away somewhere and add loads of comments about why it is necessary I may get away with it.

If anyone can find a way of not duplicating the `T[] boxed = makeTArray(it.length);` by doing it in the caller I would appreciate it.

```
public class Test {
  class A<T> {
    public void a(T... ts) {
      System.out.println(
       ts.getClass().getCanonicalName() 
       + " of " 
       + ts[0].getClass().getCanonicalName() 
       + " = " 
       + Arrays.toString(Rebox.rebox(ts)));
    }
  }

  public void test() {
    // These all work fine - presumably all parameters are autoboxed.
    new A().a(1, 2, 3);
    new A().a(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    new A().a(1L, 2L, 3L);
    // You can even mix them up - which is unexpected.
    new A().a(1.0f, 2.0d, 3L);
    // Works fine - even though I get a "non-varargs call to varargs method with inexact argument type ..." hint.
    new A().a(new Integer[]{1, 1});
    // No hint - and doesn't do as intended - Does now!!
    new A().a(new int[]{1, 1});
    new A().a(new long[]{1, 1});
    new A().a(new float[]{1, 1});
    new A().a(new double[]{1, 1});
    // Works fine.
    new A<Integer>().a(new Integer[]{1, 1});
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      new Test().test();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }

}
```

And the `Rebox` class.

```
/**
 * Can rebox a boxed primitive array into its Object form.
 *
 * Generally, if a primitive array is passed to a varargs it
 * is wrapped up as the first and only component of an Object[].
 * 
 * E.g. 
 * 
 * public void f(T... t) {};
 * f(new int[]{1,2});
 * 
 * actually ends up calling f with t an Object[1] and t[0] the int[].
 *
 * This unwraps it and returns the correct reboxed version.
 * 
 * In the above example it will return an Integer[].
 * 
 * Any other array types will be returned unchanged.
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 */
public class Rebox {
  public static <T> T[] rebox(T[] it) {
    // Default to return it unchanged.
    T[] result = it;
    // Special case length 1 and it[0] is primitive array.
    if (it.length == 1 && it[0].getClass().isArray()) {
      // Which primitive array is it?
      if (it[0] instanceof int[]) {
        result = rebox((int[]) it[0]);
      } else if (it[0] instanceof long[]) {
        result = rebox((long[]) it[0]);
      } else if (it[0] instanceof float[]) {
        result = rebox((float[]) it[0]);
      } else if (it[0] instanceof double[]) {
        result = rebox((double[]) it[0]);
      } else if (it[0] instanceof char[]) {
        result = rebox((char[]) it[0]);
      } else if (it[0] instanceof byte[]) {
        result = rebox((byte[]) it[0]);
      } else if (it[0] instanceof short[]) {
        result = rebox((short[]) it[0]);
      } else if (it[0] instanceof boolean[]) {
        result = rebox((boolean[]) it[0]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  // Rebox each one separately.
  private static <T> T[] rebox(int[] it) {
    T[] boxed = makeTArray(it.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
      boxed[i] = (T) Integer.valueOf(it[i]);
    }
    return boxed;
  }

  private static <T> T[] rebox(long[] it) {
    T[] boxed = makeTArray(it.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
      boxed[i] = (T) Long.valueOf(it[i]);
    }
    return boxed;
  }

  private static <T> T[] rebox(float[] it) {
    T[] boxed = makeTArray(it.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
      boxed[i] = (T) Float.valueOf(it[i]);
    }
    return boxed;
  }

  private static <T> T[] rebox(double[] it) {
    T[] boxed = makeTArray(it.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
      boxed[i] = (T) Double.valueOf(it[i]);
    }
    return boxed;
  }

  private static <T> T[] rebox(char[] it) {
    T[] boxed = makeTArray(it.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
      boxed[i] = (T) Character.valueOf(it[i]);
    }
    return boxed;
  }

  private static <T> T[] rebox(byte[] it) {
    T[] boxed = makeTArray(it.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
      boxed[i] = (T) Byte.valueOf(it[i]);
    }
    return boxed;
  }

  private static <T> T[] rebox(short[] it) {
    T[] boxed = makeTArray(it.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
      boxed[i] = (T) Short.valueOf(it[i]);
    }
    return boxed;
  }

  private static <T> T[] rebox(boolean[] it) {
    T[] boxed = makeTArray(it.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
      boxed[i] = (T) Boolean.valueOf(it[i]);
    }
    return boxed;
  }

  // Trick to make a T[] of any length.
  // Do not pass any parameter for `dummy`.
  // public because this is potentially re-useable.
  public static <T> T[] makeTArray(int length, T... dummy) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(dummy, length);
  }

}
```