# Java optional parameter not working as expected

Tags: java, generics, optional-parameters

I'm currently running java 7 and I found java has an odd behavior in a specific situation. The code below shows the next() of an iterator for a generic Trie data structure:

```
public final Iterator iterator = new Iterator()
{
    private int objsProcessed = 0;
    private K currentKeySequence = null;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return objsProcessed < numObjects;
    }

    @Override
    public Object next()
    {
        if (keySequences.isEmpty() == false)
        {
            currentKeySequence = keySequences.get(objsProcessed);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        objsProcessed++;
        Character[] test=new Character[]{'a','b'};
        Object result = reference.get(test);
        result = reference.get(currentKeySequence);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove()
    {
        reference.remove(currentKeySequence);
    }
};
```

Keys sequences are added in the following:

```
public Trie add(V object, K... keySequence)
{
    Node<K, V> currentNode = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < keySequence.length; i++)
    {
        currentNode = currentNode.insert(new Node<K, V>(keySequence[i],
                currentNode));
    }
    currentNode.addObject(object);
    keySequences.add((K) keySequence);
    numObjects++;
    return this;
}
```

The get method takes a variable number of arguments:

```
public List<V> get(K... keySequence)
{
    Node<K, V> currentNode = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < keySequence.length; i++)
    {
        currentNode = currentNode.getNode(keySequence[i]);
    }
    if (currentNode != null)
        return currentNode.getObjects();
    else
        return null;
}
```

The problem is that when I pass the currentKeySequence which is, in my test case, a Character[] of size 2, it makes the keySequence variable actually be an array of size 1 that contains currentKeySequence instead of just being currentKeySequence (size 2). If instead of currentKeySequence, I pass new Character[]{'a','b'} it works as expected without putting the array inside a wrapper array.

**Update:**
In other words, I have currentKeySequence = test = Character[]{'a','b'} where the only difference is that currentKeySequence  is retrieved from a list and the var test is instantiated locally with the "new" keyword.

If I pass the var test, then keySequence=Character[]{'a','b'} and if I pass currentKeySequence, then keySequence=Object[]{Character[]{'a','b'}}. I know that if I call get('a','b'), keySequence would be a Object[]{'a','b'}. I would expect that if the parameter is always wrapped into an array both situations would be the same.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Var args will be an array of fixed size containing all elements passed. If you pass an array of any size you will get an array of size one with it inside.

Comment: And you're *certain* that `currentKeySequence` is a `Character[]`?  What does `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(currentKeySequence))` give you back?

Comment: How have you defined `K`?

Comment: @GriffeyDog:  If the data structure is a trie, then `K` is likely a type parameter introduced at the class level, just like `V` would be.

Comment: Are you sure that in the first case you're passing a `Character[]` and not a `char[]`? If you pass a `char[]` of length 2 it will be wrapped when passed to the method because `T` cannot be `char` as `char` is not an `Object`. But as far as I know if you pass a `Character[]` it will never be wrapped.

Comment: @pbabcdefp:  A `char` isn't an `Object` (and can't be generalized), but a `char[]` **is** an `Object` and *can* be generalized.  This is why `List<int[]> foo = new ArrayList<>();` is a legal declaration.

Comment: If you pass an array as the only argument then this is normal? See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16856344/823393) to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854959/correctly-recognise-an-int-passed-as-a-varargs-parameter)

Comment: Can you post the code where you get the `Character[]` from the `List` and the declaration of that `List`?

Comment: What is the compile time type of the `Character[]` that you pass to the method in the first example? If it is `Object`, `T` will be treated as `Object` and it will be wrapped into an `Object[]`. If it is a `Character[]`, `T` will be treated as `Character` and it will not be wrapped. You need to show us what you're actually doing.

Comment: I added most of the code involved. According to the debugger currentKeySequence is Character[] of size 2.

Comment: @GriffeyDog, you got it. currentKeySequence which is of type Character was being assigned to Character[]. Not sure why I didn't see this before but I would have expected some type of error or to see something different in the debugger. I changed K to K[] for currentKeySequence  and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the line 
`private K currentKeySequence = null;`

K was Character but the var currentKeySequence was being assigned to Character[] (K[]). No issues were visible in the debugger or raised during runtime but when the variable was passed as parameter it was arriving in the method as Object[]{Character[]{...}}. Once K was changed to K[] in the currentKeySequence definition, the method received the correct parameter (just Character[]{...});

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug. That's how varags work.

Variable arguments (varags) allow you to pass in no argument or multiple arguments. To allow this, it uses an array to track the arguments. A single argument is not special; it's stored in the first index of the array.

Its always good to check if the array contains items before performing anything, since the client can specify no arguments for the parameter.

Comment: Both of them should count as one argument then. If I do Character[] test=new Character[]{'a','b'};Object result = reference.get(test);           it works correctly but why currentKeySequence which is basically the same as the var "test" above doesn't work? the only difference is that I retrived it from a list, the debugger still shows it as an array just like "test"

Comment: @GabrielPiacenti What do you mean? Variable argumentd are handled as arrays. If you specify an array, that array will be used. If not, a new array will be created and your arguments would be stored in them

Comment: I mean currentKeySequence = test = Character[]{'a','b'} where the only difference is that it is retrieved from a list. If I pass test then keySequence=Character[]{'a','b'} if I pass currentKeySequence then  keySequence=Object[]{Character[]{'a','b'}}

Comment: @GabrielPaicenti You cannot pass an array AND other arguments; you'll get a compile error. I'm not sure if I'm understanding you (the English on your last reply is a bit confusing)

Comment: What I'm saying is that I'm passing Character[]{'a','b'}, however, there is a difference in how it gets to the function depending on the way I'm sending it. See the updated post description

Comment: If `keySequence` is an array containing the `Character[]`, then I'm not sure why you think that would work.

Comment: @GabrielPiacenti So you're saying: if you pass in an array that was stored in a variable/list, you receive it wrapped in a new array. But, if you create an array as you're passing it in, "on the fly", it doesn't get wrapped in a new array? Is that what you're asking? I'm really having extreme difficulties understanding your problem, so I'm sorry for any miscommunication

Comment: I found the problem, see the post comments

Answer (score 2):

Your varargs structure is doing what it's told.  It's encapsulating everything you give it into an array of some type `K`.

If you pass an *array of arrays*; that is to say, if you pass in something that could be expanded to be a two-dimensional array, then the varargs will interpret that as a single argument to the varargs array.

In your question, this too would be considered a two-dimensional array:

```
new Object[]{new Character[]{'a','b'}}
```

The reason:  it's a `Character[]` nested inside of an `Object[]` (which is totally legal).

Comment: I'm not sending Object[]{new Character[]{'a','b'}}, I'm sending Character[]{'a','b'} which is being transformed into Object[]{new Character[]{'a','b'}} in one situation but not on the other.

Comment: I've provided some code in your original question's comment section to prove that this is the case.  I encourage you to do so.